# how to retrieve duplicate data using self join in detached criteria.. i wanna join Pool_id and Product_id colum

Tags: criteria, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

In this Detached Criteria i want to get duplicate Value from two Colum One Pool_id and Product_id
....

```
Object[] id1={1,2};

        DetachedCriteria poolcriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(PoolProduct.class, "PoolProduct");
        poolcriteria.add(Restrictions.in("PoolProduct.id",id1));
        System.out.println("Before list...");
        List<PoolProduct> results = poolcriteria.getExecutableCriteria(session).list();

       System.out.println("Before loop...");
        for (PoolProduct mj1 : results) {
        System.out.println("Pool ID..."+mj1.getPoolProductId());

        List<Product> poolProd = (List<Product>) mj1.getProduct();      
            for(Product mi:poolProd){
                System.out.println("Product Id..."+mi.getProductId());  
                System.out.println("Product Deascription..."+mi.getProductDescription());
            count++;    
            }
```